# onclick() automatic firing on loading but failing afterwards

Tags: javascript, html

I understand that onclick() in html with parenthesis calls automatically. But in my situation, I want to pass a parameter into the onclick function(specifically, the element clicked). So how do I manage this without having onclick fired when the page loads? In addition, the onclick method does not fire after its automatically firing upon loading. My code is below:

```
    for (i = 0; i < returnPostPhotoSrcs().length; i++)  {

//      var photosArray=returnPhotoNames()
//      var imgName=photosArray[i]

        var imgSrcArray=returnPostPhotoSrcs();
        var imgSrc=imgSrcArray[i]

        var postNamesArray=returnPostNamesArray();
        var postName=returnPostNamesArray[i]

        var img=img_create(imgSrc,postName,'')
        img.style.width=returnPostHeight();
        img.style.height=returnPostWidth();
        img.className="postImage";
        img.onmousedown=playShout(img);


        var postNamesArray=returnPostNames();
        var innerSpan = document.createElement('span');
       innerSpan.onmousedown=playShout(innerSpan); //problem line
        var text = postNamesArray[i];
        innerSpan.innerHTML = text; // clear existing, dont actually know what this does

        var outerSpan = document.createElement('span');
        outerSpan.className="text-content";
        outerSpan.onmousedown=playShout(outerSpan); //another problem line, also doesnt    call onclick


        var li = document.createElement('li');

        var imgSpacer=img_create('spacerSource',"spacer",'')
        imgSpacer.style.width="25px";
        imgSpacer.style.height=returnPostWidth();


        li.appendChild(img)
        outerSpan.appendChild(innerSpan)




        li.appendChild(imgSpacer)
        imgSpacer.style.opacity="0"






        // if (i>0 && i<returnPostPhotoSrcs().length-1) {
        //      hackey
        var imgSpacer=img_create('spacerSource',"spacer",'')
        imgSpacer.style.width="25px";
        imgSpacer.style.height=returnPostWidth();
        li.appendChild(imgSpacer)

        li.appendChild(outerSpan)

        imgSpacer.style.opacity="0"

//      }


        var outerDiv = document.getElementById("postDivOuter");
        outerDiv.appendChild(li)




    }
```

Comment: Using `returnPostPhotoSrcs()` in the loop seems like a bad idea for performance and the fact you also do it in the for loop check. Store the result in a variable outside the loop!

Comment: So a function that returns a global is really that much more expensive than directly accessing the global?

Comment: Why does it have to be a global? Every time it loops it is calling the same thing that returns the same value. It is a waste of time. It is like having to look up a phone number every single time you need to dial a phone. It is quicker if you just memorize the value.

Answer (score 0):

The function fires because you are calling it. You need to use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

```
img.onmousedown= function() { playShout(img) };
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto this you could also do:

```
img.onmousedown= function(e) { playShout(e) };

//for playshout
playshout = function(e) {
    var element = e.target; //this contains the element that was clicked
};
```

Comment: Can you guys explain why we have to surround a function with "function?"

Answer (score 0):

As others have shown, you can create an anonymous function, or another option is to use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
innerSpan.onmousedown = playShout.bind(null, innerSpan);
```